# MySQL Double way Foreign Keys?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I was wondering if this kind of thing will work:

Let's say I have two tables: COMPANIES and ADDRESSES. Each company can have only one address. Simplified schema would look like this.

```
COMPANIES
id
address_id
name
(...)

ADDRESSES
id
first_name
street
(...)
```

Now, I want to add foreign key on **COMPANIES.address_id -> ADDRESSES.id ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE**.
But I also want the address to be deleted when the company is deleted. So the other way around it would be **ADDRESSES.id -> COMPANIES.address_id ON DELETE CASCADE**. Is this safe and possible?

Comment: Are you sure you want to delete the company if you delete it's address?  What if you are removing one and adding a new one?  I would concur with the reverse case- delete the address if you delete the company.

Comment: If each company can have one address why not just have one table

Comment: @Joe From what I know, company won't be deleted if address is deleted in this case. Only address_id will be NULL. I want address to be deleted when company is deleted.

Comment: @Mark Because I use the same table with addresses with other tables.

Comment: Thus you do not want to delete an address when a company is deleted as the address could be used elsewhere

Comment: @Mark Nope. I want do delete this company address. I might also want to delete other addresses when the related object is deleted. Sometimes however, I might want the address to stay there. I just use this table for MANY different objects that have address. For example I might have another table called PEOPLE. And person can also have an address that should be deleted when person is deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe, instead of foreign keys, using triggers could be a solution to your problem.

```
create trigger addr_delete
after delete on companies for each row
begin
   delete from addresses where id=old.address_id
end
```